# Why is the textbox displayed differently when created by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why in this code the text box that is created when I press `push` is not exactly the same as the one already displayed?

```
<html>  
<body id="bd">  
<input type="text" style="width: 30px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid black"/>  
<input type="submit" value="Push" onclick="test()"/>   
<script type="text/javascript">   
function test() {   
    var txt = document.createElement('input');  
    txt.type = 'text';   
    txt.style = "width: 30px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid black";   
    document.getElementById('bd').appendChild(txt);  
}  
</script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**Update:**
What I see in the fiddle of @Bergi:

[image]

Comment: [Cannot confirm your issue](http://jsfiddle.net/Wwh6B/). Is that the whole code? What browser (version) are you using?

Comment: @Bergi:This is the exact code. Using chrome

Comment: `txt.type = 'input';` should be `text`. `input` only works because it is an invalid value and so the control uses the default instead (which is `text`).

Comment: @Quentin:Updated OP.Same problem

Comment: @Cratylus — works fine for me after making the changes I mentioned in my answer: http://jsbin.com/ipefip/2/edit

Comment: @Bergi:Please see updated OP

Comment: Change `txt.style` to `txt.style.cssText` in Bergi's fiddle, see @Quentin's answer for why. Chrome doesn't add the rules if you just insert it as one line, at least for me with v26.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `style` property isn't a string. It is an object where each CSS property is represented as a DOM property.

It also has [the `cssText` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule/cssText) which includes all the rules.

```
txt.style.cssText = "width: 30px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid black";
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what it returns when being accessed. You still can assign a whole CSS attribute string to it, and it will get parsed.

Comment: @Bergi - Not so the rules will be applied (at least not in the test I just performed in Chrome).

Comment: Oops, that seems to work only in Opera according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.style…

Answer (score 1):

For your programmatically created textbox, you're setting `txt.type = 'input';`, but in the original you set `type="text"`. Change `txt.type = 'input';` to `txt.type = 'text';`.

If you want to set the `style` in one string, use `txt.style.cssText =`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 txt.style.width ="30px";
 txt.style.padding ="2px";
 tet.style.border ="1px";
```

it really is best practice to dynamically manipulate classes via the className property since the ultimate appearance of all of the styling hooks can be controlled in a single stylesheet. One's JavaScript code also becomes cleaner since instead of being dedicated to styling details (MDN)

cssText returns the actual text of the style rule. To be able to set a stylesheet rule dynamically

```
 txt.cssText = style here;
```